# Slideshow not wrapping in browser resize unless I refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm updating a site to make it responsive. This may have not been the best approach, but my basic approach has been to add bootstrap css and js and then use row and columns to make columns on the page wrap at different sized screens.

Everything has been pretty smooth with the exception of a slideshow on the front page. This slideshow wraps pretty elegantly at all the different screen sizes when I refresh the browser, but when I'm just resizing the browser window, the column with the text on the right side of my slideshow isn't responding the way I want it to.

The slideshow is using a [jquery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). At this point, I'm working on a live test server and you can see the live example [here](http://testing.theamericanscholar.org).

My html markup looks like this:

```
    <div class="row"> 
<div class="col-xs-12">    

<div id="homepage_featured" class="rounded_shadow">
<div id="homepage_slideshow_container">
     <div id="homepage_slideshow"> 
        {% for post in slideshow_posts %}
        <div class="homepage_slide" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <center>  
                 <a href="{{ post.permalink }}"><img src="{{ post.image }}" class="img-responsive"/></a>
              </center>      
            </div> <!-- col -->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <div class="homepage_slide_copy">
                    <h4>{{ post.department }}</h4>
                    <h3><a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                        {% if post.excerpt %}<p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>{% endif %}
                    <p><strong>{{ post.author }}</strong></p>
                    <p><a href="{{ post.permalink }}" class="read_more">Read more</a></p>
                 </div> <!-- slide copy -->
           </div> <!-- col -->
           </div> <!-- row -->
       </div> <!-- homepage_slide -->
                            {% endfor %}
   </div> <!-- homepage_slideshow -->
   </div> <!-- homepage_slideshow_container -->
        <div class="row">
        <div id="homepage_slideshow_pager"></div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- homepage_featured -->
</div> <!-- col -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

And the relevant css looks like this.

```
#content #homepage_featured {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#content #homepage_slideshow {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  width: 100% !important;   
}

#content #homepage_slideshow_container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto !important;
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide {
  display: none;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide:first-child {
  display: inline;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide img {
  float: left;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide .homepage_slide_copy {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow_pager {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left:50%;
 } 
#content #homepage_slideshow_pager a {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dc4b46;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content #homepage_slideshow_pager a.activeSlide {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#content .homepage_column {
  padding: 0.7em;
  background-color: white;
}
#content .homepage_current_issue_cover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#content .homepage_column h4 a span {
  font-family: ff-meta-serif-sc-web-pro, 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Times', serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.css` file

take out all styling from  `#content #homepage_slideshow_container` and   `#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide`

and add these styles

```
#content #homepage_slideshow_container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto !important;
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #ffffff;
   height:180px; !important;; 
  overflow:hidden;

}
#content #homepage_slideshow .homepage_slide {
  display:none;
  position:relative !important;
  width:100% !important;
  height:70% !important;; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I notice when you make the window small, the slide show content next to that picture is overflowing its parent div thereby giving you an ugly look (which was solve only on refreshing the page only )..

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, that has led to a new problem. When I click on the pager to rotate slides, the slideshow wants to show two slides at once for like a split second so the container gets really tall.

Comment: It seems that the when you position and image using position:relative, the next image to be loaded pushes down the previous image and then transition fades out the previous image...when using position:absolute, each image is hidden beneath each other at 1 position..Answer edited show some hacks that can be used..you might want to adjust height in 'px' to achieve a satisfactory results.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Absolute positioning didn't work. The slide box got very narrow vertically. I actually just sped up the transition time in the js file so that the slides change instantly and the transition issue went away.

I took out the 

height: !180px important;

Because it was causing issues at the extra small browser size but everything seems to be sorted now.